# Using jplayer to stream audio after user is authenticated

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, jplayer

I am running a cakePHP application. Users upload mp3 recordings, which are stored on our server.  They can then download the .mp3 file later.

I use the CakePHP MediaViews to authenticate the user before allowing them to download the file.

```
$this->check_authorization($timeslot);
$this->viewClass = 'Media';
$params = array(
  'id' => $id . '.mp3',
  'extension' => 'mp3',
  'path' => $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/../uploads" . DS,
        'download' => true,
        'cache' =>true
    );
$this->set($params);
```

I also want to be able to let them stream the audio from their account, and am trying to use jplayer to do so.  Is there any way to provide jplayer with access to audio files not stored publicly?

Currently I am trying to have jplayer try to access the audio through a mediaView but it isn't working.  Code here:

```
//Javascript
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1", {
  mp3: "/audio/stream/test.mp3",    
    }, {
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1"
});

//Cakephp /audio/stream
function stream($name) {
  $this->viewClass = 'Media';
  $params = array(
    'id' => $name,
    'extension' => 'mp3',
    'path' => $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/../uploads" . DS,
    'download' => false,
    'cache' =>true
  );
  $this->set($params);
}
```

Is it possible to authenticate the user before streaming with jplayer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is [a whole chapter](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) in the book about authentication.

That you use something like check_authorization() looks like you have not even discovered authorization and authentication in CakePHP yet.

Comment: I use the auth component very well in the app. The question isn't about how to authenticate a user server side. It's about how to use jplayer to access the audio files of an authenticated user using the mediaViews when the audio file isn't located in the webroot (accessible via a URL). Perhaps my use of the word "authenticate" was misleading.